# which are thread-safe methods among wait(), notify(), lock(), unlock(), await(), signal(), acquire() and release()

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java multithreading and I would like to see If I am reasoning well.

From my understanding, `wait()` and `notify()` are NOT thread-safe methods (inherited from class `Object`) and for this reason, in order they to work correctly, any design expects them to be within synchronized blocks.

On the other hand, `lock()` and `unlock()` from `ReentrantLock()` class, `await()` and `signal()` from `ReentrantLock.Condition` class, `acquire()` and `release()` from `Semaphore` seem to be more high level constructs designed to be used without need of synchronized blocks. As far as I expect, this should be possible just because all these methods are natively thread-safe.

This is correct?

**EDIT: ** if object `obj` is accessed by different threads via `obj.x()`, then `obj.x()` is thread-safe if different threads can't interleave while executing it; so if a thread starts executing `obj.x()`, this call is atomic and any other thread will be put on hold for executing that method.

Comment: They are not thread-safe per se, they are tools for providing thread safe code.

Comment: The reason why `wait()` and `notify()` must be called while owning the lock is adequately described in the documentation.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "thread-safe"? You don't seem to be using any standard definition of "thread-safe", as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if object obj is accessed by different threads via obj.x(), then obj.x() is thread-safe if different threads can't interleave while executing it; so if a thread starts executing obj.

This is NOT what thread-safe means.  What you are describing there is a property known as mutual exclusion.  This is neither necessary or sufficient to guarantee true thread safety.

In fact, thread safety is rather hard to define.  You actually need to start with a section of code and a corresponding specification of correctness for that code.

> Assume that the code is correct according to the specification when executed with a single thread.
>
> Then we can say that the code is *thread-safe* if it is also correct according to the specification *for all possible executions using multiple threads*.

---

Anyhow, by the accepted definition of thread safety, all of the methods that you listed are thread-safe.  (If they weren't, then they would be useless.)

But note that that doesn't mean that everything that uses these methods is automatically thread-safe.  They have to be used the *right way*.

Comment: This answer is very helpful

Comment: Strictly speaking, mutual exclusion that provides *happens-before* edges between the different calls to a method is sufficient for thread safety in the context of that method. But yeah, in most cases we don't want the thread safety on the level of isolated methods, if that thread safety is meaningless for almost all usages of these methods (like with `Hashtable`).

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov - Yes, but ... 1) the OP is talking about *just* mutual exclusion, not mutual exclusion with *happens-before*, and 2) *happens-before* guarantees (only) visibility of updates to fields, and that is not the same as thread-safety.

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods that you've enumerated are `synchronized` or use `synchronized` blocks. Nevertheless they were all meant to be called in a multithreaded environment, so they provide the means to do this safely.

All of the `java.util.concurrent` methods you've enumerated except `Condition.await()` and `Condition.signal()` can be used without any locks being held.

- `await()` and `signal()` are roughly equivalents to `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`, so for practically all JDK implementations of the `Condition` interface, you'll need to hold the lock associated with the condition variable.

All of the `java.util.concurrent` methods you've enumerated rely on a fundamental building block for the `java.util.concurrent` package called `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer`. It's a pretty elaborate thing (there's a [whitepaper](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/aqs.pdf) for it) that can provide the functionality of the `synchronized` methods or blocks plus some additional goodies.

P.S. I assume you meant `Semaphore.release()` instead of `Semaphore.signal()`.

Comment: 'All of these methods' includes `wait()` and `notify()`, which follow different rules.

Comment: "follow different rules" is a little ambiguous, but you are right, I will clarify that the latter two paragraphs are constrained to the `java.util.concurrent` methods, excluding `wait()` and `notify()`. In the end, `wait()` and `notify()` use the same intrinsics as `await()` and `signal()`.